# Facing Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\node js programs\file' while running Node Js server

Tags: node.js

``

> This is my code for running Node js file system

```
    var http = require('http');
    var fs = require('fs');
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
      //Open a file on the server and return its content:
      fs.readFile('demofile1.html', function(err, data) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write(data);
        return res.end();
     
 });
    }).listen(3000);


``

> This is the error iam facing while running the code
```

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985 throw err; ^enter code here
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\node js programs\file'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (
{ code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', requireStack: [] }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a folder in your project node_modules?

I suspect you don't.
Please run `npm install` in your project directory.

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer?

Answer (score 5):

For me this error occurred due to incorrect path specified. Initially, I was trying this path

```
"C:\Users\abc\Documents\VS CODE\JS> node basic.js"
```

but the actual path was

```
"C:\Users\abc\Documents\VS CODE\JS\demo> node basic.js"
```

Check if you have the correct path of your file. As when you open your vscode, the terminal is set to your workspace folder not for the folder where your files actually are.

**NOTE:**

1. Delete npm and npm-cache folder from `C:\Users\appdata\roaming`
2. Add `"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm"` to your path variable.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you have specified the wrong path. Check your directory in which you are executing

Answer (score 0):

Also it happens if your folder name and the file name you are trying to execute is same. 
For example: 
**Folder name**: `scrape` 
**Js file name**: `scrape.js` 
and from `/scrape` directory you are trying to use `node scrape.js` then compiler got confused.

Answer (score -1):

This error generally occurs If you require some modules or files, which do not exists in that specified path, Please check for your required modules/imports.